# Remaining days calculation in java

Tags: java, android, algorithm, android-calendar

I have implemented the following code to calculate the remaining days left. I have used SimpleDateFormat to convert string to date. If I enter 10/02/1993 (today's date) as the date, the output shows 0 days left. But if I choose 11/02/1993, it shows the same output as 0 days left. But if I change the month i.e. 22/07/1993, it shows 160 days left instead of 162 days, which is the original result. What am I doing wrong here ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
private static void calculateNextBirthday() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your birthday(dd/MM/yyyy)");
        user_input = in.nextLine();

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        Calendar user_selected_day = new GregorianCalendar();

        Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();

        Date selected_date = null;
        try {
            selected_date = formatter.parse(user_input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        user_selected_day.setTime(selected_date);

        int user_selected_month = user_selected_day.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int CMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        int user_selected_date = user_selected_day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int CDate = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        user_selected_day.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        user_selected_day.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

        if (user_selected_month < CMonth) {
            user_selected_day.set(Calendar.YEAR,today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
        }
        else if (user_selected_month == CMonth){
            if(user_selected_date < CDate){
                user_selected_day.set(Calendar.YEAR,today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);  
            }
        }

        long millis = user_selected_day.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();
        long days;
        days = (millis / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(days) + " days left!!");
    }
```

> UPDATE : I have updated the Code below and it works fine. Hope it helps someone in the future.

```
`       SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        Calendar user_selected_day = new GregorianCalendar();

        Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();

        Date selected_date = null;

        try {
            selected_date = formatter.parse(plainDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        user_selected_day.setTime(selected_date);

        int user_selected_month = user_selected_day.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int CMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        int user_selected_date = user_selected_day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int CDate = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        user_selected_day.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        user_selected_day.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,today.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        user_selected_day.set(Calendar.MINUTE,today.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        user_selected_day.set(Calendar.SECOND,today.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        user_selected_day.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,today.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));


        if (user_selected_month < CMonth) {
            user_selected_day.set(Calendar.YEAR,today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
        }
        else if (user_selected_month == CMonth){
            if(user_selected_date < CDate){
                user_selected_day.set(Calendar.YEAR,today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);  
            }

        }

        long millis = user_selected_day.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();
        long days;
        if(user_selected_day.getTime()==today.getTime()){
            days = 0;
        }
        else{
            days = (millis / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        }`
```

Comment: Note : `/24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` will not always work because of Daily Saving Time (DST) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: Ok. So what will be the solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the lines

```
user_selected_day.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

This will set the year of today's date to `user_selected` day and as month is equal it will go inside **elseif** and go out of the same without making any changes.

Also check the if else condition you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `LocalDate` class in Java 8, to add/subtract dates on the go.

> `java.time` offers a `Period` class to represent a length of time, such as
>   a number of days, or hours and minutes. `LocalDate` and friends offer
>   `plus()` and `minus()` methods to add or subtract a Period or other
>   time-related object. Period offers factory methods such as `ofDays()`.

read this example for reference. It computes what the date will be `700` days from now:

```
/**
 * DateAdd -- compute the difference between two dates (e.g., today and 700 days
 * from now).
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] av) {
        /** Today's date */
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        Period p = Period.ofDays(700);
        LocalDate then = now.plus(p);
        System.out.printf("Seven hundred days from %s is %s%n", now, then);
    }
}
```

Running this program reports the current date and time, and what the date and time will be seven hundred days from now. For example:

```
Seven hundred days from 2013-11-09 is 2015-10-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not make the calculation yourself. Once you have the Calendar objects, use the "add" method to increment the value you want.